# Vue child component props not updating

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

In all the other questions I could find data was being used preventing reactivity. Here data is not being used, the prop itself is failing to update in rendering.

My VueX functions are:

`addItemColumn()` creates a new column in the first Box, essentially boxes aren't allowed to grow on their own; However, the parent can requests that a new column is added (to the first box.)

`MoveBoxDown()` should be self-explanatory, but switches the current box (which this function is called on) with the one below it.

Here's what happens...

When just item column is executed an additional column with the default item is correctly added and re-rendered. However, when moveBoxDown is executed first what happens is the boxes switch correctly and re-render but then when I go to execute addItemColumn the child, Box, does not see any update to the Box.

What is strange is 
1) `addItemColumn()` works and renders 
2) `moveBoxDown()` works and renders

So it wouldn't seem a failure to update moveBoxDown propagates causing the problem to addItemColumn. As a matter of fact, running `moveBoxDown()` with any of my other mutations works perfectly.

3) Vue Devtools show that the Box is updated and for that matter `box.items` is updated
4) Per the example code `<p>{{ box.items.length }}<p>` updates in the parent but not the child, Box.

If it didn't work in the parent I might think it was a keying issue for the child; however, it does and in combination with devtools correctly showing the updated `box` on the child it seems to me for some unknown reason to me the child is not detecting the prop has been updated?

The only way I can think to fix this is to turn Box into a slotted component since the parent is aware and this would seem to mitigate the issue.

I have the following data structure in VueX

```
Boxes = [
  {
    id: number
    items: [
      {
        id: number
        properties: {
          ...
        }
      },
      ...
    ]
  },
  ...
]
```

An item is being added using `.push()` in VueX, triggered by `addBox` so the change is detected. Again, in general  this works but there are instances where it refuses to update even when Vue Dev tools show the correct, now updated, prop value.

Parent

```
<template>
  <b-button @click="addBox()">Add Box</b-button>

  <div v-for="(box, index) in boxes" :key="`box_${index}`">
    <!-- This updates so is not related to the parents loop -->
    <p>{{ box.items.length }}</p>
    <Box :box="box" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
// Import VueX
import { mapGetters, mapActions } from "vuex";

// Import Components
import Box from "~/components/Box";

export default {
  name: "BoxesPage",
  layout: "BoxesLayout",
  components: { Box },
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters({
      boxes: "items/boxes"
    })
  },
  methods: {
    ...mapActions({
      addItemColumn: "items/addItemColumn"
    })
  },
  async fetch({ store, params }) {
    await store.dispatch("items/getInventory");
  }
};
</script>
```

Box

```
<template>
  <div>
    <!-- Neither of these update either, so this is not related to the child's loop -->
    <p>{{ box }}<p>
    <p>{{ box.items.length }}<p>
    <b-button
      @click="moveBoxDown()"
      icon-right="chevron-down"
    />
    <div
      v-for="item in box.items"
      :key="
      `box_${box.index}_item_${item.index}_${item.name}`"
    >
      <!-- This does not add a new item -->
      <Item :item="item" />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
// Import VueX
import { mapGetters, mapActions } from "vuex";

// Import Components
import Item from "~/components/Item";

export default {
  name: "Box",
  components: { Item },
  props: {
    Box: {
      type: Object,
      required: true
    }
  },
  methods: {
    ...mapActions({
      moveBoxDown: "items/moveBoxDown",
    })
  }
};
</script>
```

I won't attach the VueX lines since again the VueX implementation appears to be completely fine... whether it correctly re-renders or doesn't the Vue Dev tools show the prop was correctly updated.

Edit:
VueX "items.js"

```
export const state = () => ({
  boxes: []
});

export const actions = {
  moveFrameDown({ commit }, frameIndex) {
    commit('switchBoxes', { fromIndex: frameIndex, toIndex: frameIndex + 1 });
  },
  addBoxColumn({ commit }, item) {
    // Item is a default item type
    commit('newItemColumn', item);
  },
}

export const mutations = {
  SwitchBoxes: (state, { fromIndex, toIndex }) => {
    state.boxes[fromIndex] = {
      index: fromIndex,
      items: state.boxes.splice(toIndex, 1, {
        index: toIndex,
        items: state.frames[fromIndex].items
      })[0].items
    };
  },
  newItemColumn: (state, itemProps) => {
    state.boxes[0].items.push({
      id: state.idCounter
      props: itemProps
    });
    state.idCounter += 1;
  }
};
```

Comment: What specifically doesn't update? Does the additional box not get displayed on the screen when you add a box (an issue with the array), or are the properties of an existing box not updating (an issue with the box object)? The view not updating is 99% of the time caused by either not declaring reactive data correctly upfront, or mutating an array/object in a way that Vue cannot detect, but since you have omitted that code it is difficult to pinpoint the exact issue.

Comment: Yes, sorry, to clarify when a new box is added it does not update. I see if I can add the VueX code or make a JSFiddle. It's a bit complicated to show all the code to produce the error as it's a bit of an edge case.

Comment: @DecadeMoon I've added examples of the VueX functions and clarified the specific edge case as well as what should happen and what is happening further. I'm not sure it will be particularly helpful to see the VueX since as I mention all the way down to the DevTools and Parent the state of `box` after updating is correctly represented and rendered. As far as I can tell this seems like an odd issue where the prop is not triggering an update between the parent and the child, Box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your example is not very minimal, so I can only guess what might be the cause.

This is a red flag:

```
state.boxes[fromIndex] = { ... }
```

From the [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#For-Arrays):

> Vue cannot detect the following changes to an array:
>
> 1. When you **directly set an item with the index**, e.g. `vm.items[indexOfItem] = newValue`
> 2. When you modify the length of the array, e.g. `vm.items.length = newLength`

You are also doing a `splice()` on the array at the same time, which Vue can detect, so coincidentally the array change will probably be reflected in the view, however what you may not realize is that the new object you assigned to the array index will not be reactive.

You need to use [`Vue.set()`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-set):

```
Vue.set(state.boxes, fromIndex, { ... })
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This small detail was it, first time working with Vue/VueX and seems I got too cocky thinking I did everything perfectly and focusing too much on debugging (confirmation bias.) I do find it strange that Vue Devtools showed the data updating though in the child, perhaps the devtools don't guarantee this or this is a weird case in Vue. Regardless I've now learned my lesson in Vue -- Always double check -- thank you so much!